# How to add div banner before every page content using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example, there is the following page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .a {
        background-color: red;
      }
      .b {
        background-color: yellow;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="a">123</div>

    <div>456</div>

    <script>
      var banner = document.createElement("div");
      banner.className = "b";
      banner.innerHTML = "Banner Content";

      var content = document.getElementsByClassName("a")[0];
      content.parentNode.insertBefore(banner, content);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I just add 'banner' div before first page item. But this code isn't universal; if items are absolute positioned, my code doesn't work. I need to create some JS which will add 'banner' div before page content for every situation. Is it possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you thought prepending it to document.body?

Answer (score 3):

**Updated** for prepend in body as on @Quentin comment

You can use `document.body` to insert the div before every element like,

```js
var banner = document.createElement("div");
banner.className = "b";
banner.innerHTML = "Banner Content";

document.body.insertBefore(banner,document.body.childNodes[0]);
```

```css
.a {
  background-color: red;
}
.b {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">123</div>

<div>456</div>
```

Comment: That inserts between the head and the body, which is invalid.

Comment: Would it work if elements in body are absolute positioned?

Comment: If your elements are `positioned` then you need to use higher `z-index` and `top:0` of `.b` and `position` property to make it visible on every element.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), the first parameter determines position in relation to the target element (e.g. first child of body is `afterbegin`). The second parameter is the string that will be rendered as HTML to be inserted (e.g. `<div class="b">Banner Content</div>`).

The first parameter must be one of the following:

1. 'beforebegin': Before the element itself.
2. 'afterbegin' : Just inside the element, before its first child.
3. 'beforeend'  : Just inside the element, after its last child.
4. 'afterend'   : After the element itself.

#### SNIPPET

```js
var target = document.body;

target.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "<div class='b'>Banner Content</div>");
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .a {
      background-color: red;
    }
    .b {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="a">123</div>

  <div>456</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Would it work if elements in body are absolute positioned?

Comment: Make your banner `position: relative;` But it'll still work if it isn't `position:relative`, , it's just easier if the banner is in the flow with the rest of your layout.

Comment: I don't know which site will be used. It can be different

Comment: It'll work regardless of layout really. The only thing I can think of that might be a problem is if the first child of body is at the very top and is `position: absolute`. If the banner is inserted and is static (i.e. normal; `position: static`), then one would overlap the other. If the header was `absolute` then it should push the first child down if it is `relative` or `absolute`. These are common concerns of style while your concern is if it works. Short answer: always.  It would be common sense to design your pages so that there's enough space for the banner in the first place, correct?